# Is it possible to "concatenate" results of a query?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm implementing a book search function based on authors. I should return a query result that contains all the books written by the queried author. However, it is possible that a query for certain author names returns multiple results (e.g., a query of "Smith, W" might match "Smith, Wesson" and "Smith, Will").

So, my problem is how to "concatenate" all the books written by these different authors. If I don't consider the possibility of multiple authors matching a query, I'd go about something like this (in pseudocode, as my real code is quite messy right now):

- search author table for the author
- matching the query
- get author's authorid
- search book table for book records with the same authorid

However, with the possibility of multiple authors, I have something like this in mind:

```
// search author table for authors matching the query

foreach(author_match as am){
  // search book table for book records with authorid=am.authorid
  // Is there such thing as this? :\
  book_results += all the rows returned by previous query
}
return book_results;
```

I'm doing this in PHP (with CodeIgniter Framework) and MySQL. Is there any function/operator that will allow me to do this? Yes, I've tried `+=`, even if I wasn't expecting much from it, to an ugly output.

Again, my apologies for the pseudocode. I'll try to clean-up my code and edit ASAP but if an answer comes before that, it'd be just as awesome. Thanks.

Comment: What is wrong with JOINing books and authors in a query?

Comment: I don't know Codeigniter well, but the query you need looks something like:  `SELECT author.*, book.* FROM author LEFT JOIN book ON author.authorid = book.authorid WHERE author.authorid = <your query author>`

Comment: I admittedly haven't looked into JOINS yet. Will try them and report back later. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Michael, it seems you need either an `INNER JOIN` or a `LEFT JOIN`.

You say you are using Codeigniter so here is a Codeigniter specific example:

```
$this->db->select('author.*, 
                   book.*');
$this->db->from('authors');
$this->db->join('books', 'books.authorid = authors.id', 'left');
$this->db->where('authors.id', $the_author_id);
```

Also see:

- [Codeigniter's Activerecord documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select)
- [Other Codeigniter JOIN questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=codeigniter%20join)

Comment: Figured out how to use joins in my query but thanks for the CodeIgniter-specific example (--,)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.=` to concatenate. However, more efficiently, you can simply specify multiple WHERE clauses in the SQL, so you'd have the following pseudocode:

```
search author table for authors matching the query
where = 'with '
foreach(author_match as am){
where += 'authorid=' . am.authorid . ' OR' }
where = substr(where[0,strlen(where)-3)
}
search book table for book records [where clause here]
return book_results
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can modify your query to use LEFT JOIN.  This way you can get multiple query results in one query.

Comment: Ummm, MySQL implements `UNION`s as, well, `UNION`s.  `LEFT JOIN` is an entirely different concept.

Answer (score -1):

To do a concatenate in PHP, use

```
.=
```

Comment: The `+=` was part of pseudocode, and `.=` is a string concatenator, supremely unhelpful for appending query results...

Comment: He wants to concatenate strings. Unless, of course you have a better way to store the names of things. 

Declare a variable, then open the query result loop and .= the results.

Comment: Besides, I figured that `.=` is exclusively string and `+=` is for, ummm, everything else, numeric data and etc. (apparently not). Yes, even in my real code, I tried `+=`. I want to concatenate records, which, AFAIK are pointers/cursors, not strings.